# Google won't stop asking me to agree to new features for text messaging

Tags: samsung, sms

I keep getting the following pop up message on my phone.

"Faster, richer, higher-quality chat on Wi-Fi or data

To turn on chat features from Google, you agree to the Terms of Service. Google will occasionally verify your number by exchanging your device info with your operator. (SMS charges may apply.) Google's Privacy Policy describes how data is handled. Learn more."

I refuse to agree and select continue without new features but it won't stop popping up.  It is so frustrating.

Any suggestions?

[image: popup]